# show alert on cubit state in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I know we can return different widgets on certain state of cubit, but how can we show an alert or other interactions on states:

```
BlocBuilder<LoginCubit, LoginState> (
  builder: (context, LoginState loginState) {
    if (loginState is LoginInitial) {
      return Text("LoginInitial");
    } else if (loginState is LoginLoading) {
      return Text("LoginLoading");
    } else if (loginState is LoginLoaded) {
      return Text("LoginLoaded");
    } else if (loginState is LoginError) {
      return Text("LoginError");
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  },
)
```

here in LoginError I want to show an alert dialog.

Comment: Can't you just call the function `showDialog(AlertDialog dialog)` before you return Text("LoginError")? The return part should build the widget you are displaying while showDialog builds the dialog on another layer.

Comment: no, it returned me an error, it just takes a widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BlocConsumer`, which has both a `builder` and a `listener`:

- The `builder` attribute is the widget builder callback you already know
- The `listener` is a callback called when the state changes and you can do pretty much anything there.

For more fine grained control you can use `buildWhen` and `listenWhen`, which trigger respectively the `builder` or `listener` callbacks if they return `true`.

For example you can see how I've used `BlocConsumer` to show a `SnackBar` when an error state occurs [here](https://github.com/magicleon94/corona_italy/blob/59232ccaf8923a82eb834b4061ff6b9f664ab920/lib/features/infection_report/presentation/widgets/infections_map.dart#L23).

Don't mind the double check on the type

```
if (state is RegionalReportLoadingError)
```

because it's probably useless (according to the docs) and I just wanted to be sure about that when I did not have the usage of `listenWhen` very clear.

You can check more about `BlocConsumer` in [the docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) (Unfortunately I cannot link the anchor).

Comment: I know, and it's awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

Showing dialogs, snackbars, exiting the screen or navigating somewhere else - these kind of tasks should be done in listeners, like this:

```
useCubitListener<BookDetailsCubit, BookDetailsPageState>(cubit, (cubit, state, context) {
  state.maybeWhen(
    saveBook: () => context.router.pop<bool>(true),
    deleteBook: () => context.router.pop<bool>(true),
    orElse: () => null,
  );
}, listenWhen: (state) => (state is BookDetailsPageSaveBook || state is BookDetailsPageDeleteBook));
```

Here I used cubits with hooks. `useCubitListener()` is a global function. More on this in my [Flutter cubits + hooks tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).